# Как задать ограничение в Django, чтобы выводились данные только за последние сутки из БД( SQLite )

Tags: python, django, база-данных

Нужно чтобы на выходе был отчёт с данными за последние сутки.
Мой код выводит все данные. Как поставить ограничение?
Если возможно в цикле {% if Datapack.downloaded   %}.

Вот HTML

```
        <tr>Отчёт о данных за последние сутки</tr>
                       <tr>
                           <th>Имя файла<th>
                           <th>Размер файла, байт</th>
                           <th>Дата принятия</th>
                           <th>Оператор</th>
                       </tr>

            {% for Datapack in  Datapacks %}
              *{% if Datapack.downloaded  ???? %}*

                       <tr>
                           <td><div>{{Datapack.filename }}</div> </td>
                           <td><div>{{Datapack.size }}</div></td>
                           <td><div>{{Datapack.downloaded }}</div></td>
                           <td><div>{{Datapack.uploader}}</div></td>
                       </tr>
                    </thead>
                   {% endif %}
                  {% endfor %}`
```

Модель

```
class Datapack(models.Model):
code = models.UUIDField(
    auto_created=True, default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True, editable=False
)
filename = models.CharField("Имя файла", max_length=200)
location = models.CharField("Расположение на диске", max_length=1000, blank=True, null=True)
size = models.BigIntegerField("Размер файла, байт", blank=True, null=True)
downloaded = models.DateTimeField("Дата принятия", blank=True, null=True)
uploader = models.UUIDField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from isist.models import Datapack
 def index(request):
 Datapacks = Datapack.objects.all()
 return render (request, 'otchet/otchet.html', {'Datapacks': Datapacks })
```

Comment: Datapacks = Datapack.objects.all() Запроси не все данные а за последние сутки!!!

Comment: В том то и проблема, что не понимаю, как?

Comment: one_day_ago = timezone.now() - timedelta(day=1)                                                         Datapacks.objects.filter(downloaded>one_day_ago) # при условии что там одинаковые величины!!! проверьте

Comment: ответ ниже используйте для правки: days !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Отфильтруйте данные при запросе в БД:

```
from django.utils import timezone
from datetime import timedelta

...
one_day_ago = timezone.now() - timedelta(days=1)
Datapacks = Datapack.objects.filter(downloaded__gte=one_day_ago)
...
```

Comment: Вот так?  from django.shortcuts import render
from isist.models import Datapack
from django.utils import timezone
from datetime import timedelta


def index(request):
    one_day_ago = timezone.now() - timedelta(day=1)
    Datapacks = Datapack.objects.filter(downloaded__gte=one_day_ago)
    return render (request, 'otchet/otchet.html', {'Datapacks': Datapacks })  Но выходит ошибка: "'day' is an invalid keyword argument for __new__()"

Comment: Писал по памяти, должно быть `days`

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!!!